# Make one select field depend to another in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I have Django model as follows:

```
class UserBusinessUnit(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(to=Company, limit_choices_to={'is_dealership': True})
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    brands = models.ManyToManyField(to=Brand)
    business_unit = models.ForeignKey(to=BusinessUnit)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user__username',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.email + ' - ' + self.business_unit.name
```

In Django admin panel it look like this:

[image]

I want to be able to populate `User` and `Business unit` field depending in `Company` field.

Thus if I change `company` field I want that the `User` and `Business` field are instantly populated.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You are going to need to delve into JavaScript for that sort of functionality. You could handle it on the server side, but it makes a lot more sense to do it in JavaScript.